Using http_poller to request something from an elasticsearch host that's not local
I want to ask if there is a way we can use http_poller to request something from an elasticsearch host that's not local. Like this below:
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      es_data => {
        method => get
        url => "https://your-elasticsearch-domain:9200/earthquake-3/_search"
        headers => {
          Accept => "application/json"
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        }
        body => '{
          "sort": [
            {
              "DateTime": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          ],
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "size": 1
        }'
        auth => {
          user => "https://learningmachinelearning.es.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243"
          password => ""
        }
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    schedule => { every => "5m" }
    codec => "json"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

It gives me this on output. I know this works on local but is there a way to make this work on a different elasticsearch host
{
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_http_request_failure"
    ],
         "event" => {
        "duration" => 1180000
    },
         "error" => {
        "stack_trace" => nil,
            "message" => "No such host is known (your-elasticsearch-domain)"
    },
          "host" => {
        "hostname" => "DESKTOP-D13AKCK"
    },
           "url" => {
        "full" => "https://your-elasticsearch-domain:9200/earthquake-3/_search"
    },
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2024-05-23T10:21:57.253296800Z,
          "http" => {
        "request" => {
            "method" => "get"
        }
    }
}

Is there a way to access an elasticsearch host through http_poller. Also, let me explain why I was trying to do it, I actually wanted to sort and retrieve the result of a query. I wasn't able to sort it any other way, this approach worked on local but I haven't figured a way to do this on a cloud elasticsearch. Let me know if it's something that's possible through http_poller or not.

why you want to use http_poller and not elasticsearch input plugin ? elasticsearch input plugin will support external host as well and not only localhost. Also, it will support sort and scheduling as well.

Hi Sagar, ty for your response. Actually I tried doing it with the input plugin but I wasn't able to sort and retrieve query results like this which is why I tried using http_poller. If you guide me to how it can be done through input plugin since that is my main concern that I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Below is sample example of elasticsearch input plugin. This will used same query which you have mentioned in above question:
input {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => "https://your-elasticsearch-domain:9200"
        index => "earthquake-3"
        query => '{"sort":[{"DateTime":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":1}'
        schedule => { cron => "*/5 * * * * UTC"}
      }
    }
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

